# Internet Slow Down in VPN

Tags: windows-xp

We've 10mb/sec line and we’re getting the speed of 900KB/Sec normally but in VPN we’re getting 15 to 18 KB/Sec.

In VPN we’re using the client proxy server for internet. Also when we copy some data of 50 MB from client server to our local machine we get very slow response.

Please advice how much speed I can get in VPN at my site and as you know we’ve 10mbps line

Comment: Do you have 100% control over all VPN settings?

Comment: Is the port you're connecting too public and is it being thrashed ? (This is exactly what happened to me!) Check in the EventLog of the source machine.

Comment: This is impossible to answer. There are two many variables. For example, what is providing the VPN? Are the terminators routers, firewalls, PC's? Is one of the terminators sharing VPN terminations e.g. Firewall or router. What type of VPN? What key lengths, what encryption ......